# How to get python monkeypatching to work?

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to patch a function called `get_datetime()`.

The real date time `get_datetime()` is located under `bobs/utils/dtutils` and does:

```
def get_datetime() -> datetime:
    return datetime.now()
```

this gets used in another place under `bobs/generation`

where globally in the `generation.py` file i do:

```
from utils.dtutils import get_datetime
NAME = f"""{KMTER}/{get_datetime().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}/dadsdge.fs"""
```

in the monkey patch i do:

```
monkey_patch.setattr(
    "bobs.generation.get_datetime",
    datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 18),
)
```

this doesn't work. I still get `now()` returned.

I also tried patching `bobs.utils.dtutils.get_datetime` to no avail either. It definitely finds it because if i make up the function name it says `module does not contain bla`, so i don't understand why i'm not seeing it set...

Comment: Unrelated, but why define `get_datetime` in the first place? Seems like an unnecessary level of indirection (even if you go with the simpler definition `get_datetime = datetime.now`).

Comment: Can do. Let me know if you know why the monkey patching fails. This seems to be failing if i just try monkey patching a string

Comment: "This gets used in another place under bobs/generation where globally in the generation.py file I do [...]": in this case, aren't you missing a "generation" in your patch, like "bobs.generation.generation.get_datetime"?

Comment: no sorry i should have wrote bobs/generation.py